# Why is `ref.current.clientHeight` always 19

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, ref

If I set the height of `<div className="scale" ref={ref}>` with CSS to 400 px, I expect `ref.current.clientHeight` to be 400 px but it's always 19.

**How do I get the height of the div?**

My plan is to set it to 100% and still know the height of the div.

```css
.scale {
   height: 400px;
   display: block;
}
```

```js
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect, useRef } from "react";

function Scale() {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current && ref.current.clientHeight) {
      setHeight(ref.current.clientHeight);
    }
  });
  return (
    <div className="scale" ref={ref}>
      {height}
    </div>
  );
}

export { Scale };
```

The reason it was always 19 was that all the parent divs, body and Html needed to have their height set to `100vh`

Comment: When you inspect the DOM, what is the div's height?

Comment: it was indeed 19px because it was being constrained by its parent's height, it was 100% of the parent which was 19px

Comment: Better to give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and focus on one question in your post, and since you have self solved your problem, if you think this can't help others, kindly remove it would be preferred

Comment: Thank your for your suggestion the code can be reproduced an I’m sure it will be helpful to others